# Create ODBC Connection from Access to SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, odbc, microsoft-access, linked-server

I need help connecting from a blank access 2010 database to my remote SQL Server 2005 database. This is because I'm going to write all my client apps in Access, and store everything on the server with SQL Server. I'm using the wizard, and trying to make a new DSN. What do I put for:

```
Which SQL Server do you want to connect to?
Server:
```

The server is windows server 2008, and it is remote. I've been connecting to it with a .RDP file, but I'm not sure how to set up the link. The .RDP connects to mail.blahblahblah.com, where blahblahblah is the domain name. So I put:

```
mail.blahblahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS
```

I've also tried:

```
blahblahblah.com\SQLEXPRESS
```

I keep getting SQL Server Error: 53, server does not exist or access denied. Could you guys help me figure out what I put for the server name? Thanks

Please ask me to clarify anything that doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server name is the server name.  It should resolve to an IP address via DNS or some other resolution method.  Of course you will need to make sure you can actually reach that address through any firewalls or other devices between you at the server.

Comment: So, I've pinged both mail.blahblahblah.com and blahblahblah.com, they both resolve to IP's, but only blahblahblah.com responds. I'm convinced I'm using the wrong name, the only information I have about the server is the string that I connect through the .RDP file(mail.blahblahblah.com), and the instance name. I also know the name of the computer that I get remote access to(It's called TERM). How can I find the correct server name?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is the server not hosted on your own network?  Since you can RDP to it, why not just grab the IP address, which will be visible in the network properties?  If it isn't on  your local network, then as I mentioned, even if did have the right name, you are probably being blocked by firewalls, and you will need to create a VPN or something.

Comment: The server is hosted in Blaine, WA. I'm in Bellingham. The guy who runs the server gave me a .RDP file and I just connect with that. The .RDP uses mail.blahblah.com. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use this mail subdomain or what. He made an account for me, with a username and password. Maybe I am being blocked by firewalls, I'll try to figure that out, thanks.

Comment: Call the guy who runs/owns the server and ask him if he can help you setup a VPN or something.  That is what you probably want/need.